# First Derivative Test for local extremum

Tags: calculus

Is it necessary that the first derivative will change sign at an extremum it it exists at that point. If yes then how to prove it?
I want to know that if we consider the function $$f(x)=\left(2-\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)|x|$$ for $x$ not equal to 0 and $$f(x)=0$$ for $x=0$ has a minimum at $x=0$ but the function is not monotonic either on left or the right of $0.$

Comment: for proof of first derivative test [Check Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeAppsProofs.aspx)

Comment: No, it is not. Consider the function $f(x)=0$.

Comment: No I want to know that if we consider the function $$f(x)=(2-sin\frac{1}{x})|x|$$ for $x$ not equal to 0 and $$f(x)=0$$ for $x=0$ has a minimum at $x=0$ but the function is not monotonic either on left or the right of $0$

Comment: @JohnDouma Only if you define extrema weakly.

Comment: @user679770 Is your function differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: But the first derivative test doesn't require the function to be differentiable at the concerned point

Comment: @user679770 It doesn't, but your question does. You said, *Is it necessary that the first derivative will change sign at an extremum if it exists at that point?* Perhaps you want to reframe more carefully. Also, I suggest you add the original motivating function in OP. Not everyone looks in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is this -- we're not concerned about monotony in half-neighbourhoods of $x=0.$ What's important is that the derivative change sign across the point. And for the example you give, it does. Since for $x\ne 0$ we have that $$f'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\cos\frac1x\right)|x|+\left(2-\sin\frac1x\right)\frac{x}{|x|},$$ it follows that for $x>0,$ we have $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\cos\frac1x+2-\sin\frac1x,$$ and when $x<0,$ we have that $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x}\cos\frac1x-2+\sin\frac1x.$$

Now these always have opposite sign in their respective domains, so it follows that in any (punctured) neighborhood of $x=0,$ the derivative does change sign, as required.

In general, it is necessary that the derivative change sign at an internal extremum, for otherwise the point would not be a local extremum (note that here we use the strict definition of local extrema).

Comment: $f'$ has to change sign while passing through $x=0$ but in this case $f'$ is changing sign in every neighbourhood of $0$ so we cannot say that in a certain right neighbourhood of $0$ $f'$ is positive and in certain left neighbourhood of $0$ $f'$ is negative

Comment: @user679770 On the contrary, $f'(x)$ changes sign from $x<0$ to $x>0$ since $f'(x),$ as shown above, has different signs in each half neighborhood. It doesn't matter that it is not monotonic (there's nothing like that in the theorem!). The fact is that *the sign of the derivative in one half-neighbourhood of $0$ is always opposite that in the other neighborhood -- this is all that is necessary.* I  think the problem is that somehow you're unnecessarily making the additional assumption that the function must be monotonic in some neighborhood of the point. There's nothing like this required.